# Creating a Continuous File Reading-Executing Shell Script

Tags: shell, text, executable, continuous

I need to write something that will read and execute all the files(Mainly executable scripts) inside one or more folders; in other words, a continuous chain with a break when finished. I'm new to shell and need syntax help. I'm on Ubuntu 12.10-Gnome btw.
 
Here are some main highlights I think should be included;
-The program should ask for one or more directories. Should process all the files given in these directories,

-Should create a .txt file on which files and folders are read and executed(for correction and informational purposes),

-Could contain a break option like control+shift+c maybe but thats clearly not of utmost importance.

The code, or the guidance to the code would be very much appreciated. Thx alot.

Comment: So where is what you have so far and where do you get stuck?

Comment: I've tried a couple of stuff yet I got all bundled up and decided to do something fresh.I'm a bit clueless on what to do, came for tips to start with.